# Saving Elements of List in R - Number of Files doesnt match length of list

Tags: r, list, csv, dplyr, save

I have two lists that contains only of dataframes.
My goal is to save their elements, individually as csv.
However, no matter which method I try, at the end the output folder does not contain the same amount of csv files as the list has elements.

For example.
List length = 150
Number of CSVs in output folder = 122

My trials:

1. lapply

```
    lapply(names(price_list_raw), function(x) {
      x1 <- price_list_raw[[x]]
      write_csv(x1, file=paste0("C:/Users/XXX",'/', x, '.csv'))
    })
```

2. Stone-Age like loop

```
    for (i in 1: length(price_list_raw)){
      nam <- names(price_list_raw[i])
      output_folder <- paste0("C:/Users/XXX",'/',nam,".csv")
      write_csv(price_list_raw[[i]],
                output_folder
      )
      print(i)
    }
```

What am I missing?
When i look through the list and its elements, they are all data frames

Any suggestion?

Kind regards

Comment: What is the value of `length(unique(names(price_list_raw)))`?

Comment: `readr::write_csv`'s second argument is `path=`, not `file=`. Are you using a different one?

Comment: @r2evans in the first case, OP mentioned `file=`, which is an argument in `write_csv`

Comment: Yes, but if the user has a version of `readr` before 1.4.0, then they do not have `file=`, they have `path=`. See https://readr.tidyverse.org/news/index.html, under 1.4.0 and "breaking changes" (because *that* is a breaking change).

Comment: @r2evans I understand that part, but if that is the case the OP wouldn't get any files written. As per his post `List length = 150 Number of CSVs in output folder = 122`

Comment: Fair point, thanks.

Comment: @mikebader length(unique(names(price_list_raw))) is somehow one number higher than the number of elements in the list. How is that?

Comment: I don't know -- I was asking because, as @akrun pointed out, the names could include duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looping over the `names` which can be duplicates, loop over the sequence of elements

```
lapply(seq_along(price_list_raw), function(x) {
      x1 <- price_list_raw[[x]]
      write_csv(x1, file=paste0("C:/Users/XXX",'/', names(price_list_raw)[x], x, '.csv'))
    })
```

---

Also, as mentioned in the comments, if there are duplicate names, then one option is to loop over the names by making it unique

```
names(price_list_raw) <- make.unique(names(price_list_raw))
lapply(names(price_list_raw), function(x) {
      x1 <- price_list_raw[[x]]
      write_csv(x1, file=paste0("C:/Users/XXX",'/', x, '.csv'))
    })
```

The usage in `write_csv` is

```
write_csv(
  x,
  file,
  na = "NA",
  append = FALSE,
  col_names = !append,
  quote_escape = "double",
  eol = "\n",
  path = deprecated()
)
```